# Best material settings to recreate the "20 century fox" letters?

Tags: materials

Best material settings to recreate the "20 century fox" letters?[image]

Full sequence here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNnsuxcOcIY&ab_channel=Alan

Comment: Hello, it looks pretty basic, what have you tried so far and why didn't it work? Maybe share your file or at least a part of it?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer:) Yes, I know it seems kind of a basic material, but I still struggling to find the right balance between the base material, and the texture and even the lightning... and still struggling to get the result I want... any advice? BTW- the letters mean in Hebrew "Happy birthday":)

Comment: maybe share a part of your file so that we can try to modify it?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I thought I could upload the file here, I will upload the file in a few minutes to an external service and will share a link... thanks!

Comment: Here is a link to the file , thanks! file:https://easyupload.io/kthv48

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it is more a problem of HDRI and lighting than a problem of material. I would do it in 3 steps:

- First choose the good HDRI image, a landscape by sunset, here I've used an image from the 20th Century Fox itself. In the *Shader Editor* lower down its lighting effect with an *Input > Light Path* as factor:

[image]

- Create a *Sun* light with a *Strength* of 4 or about 4.3 (as neutral as possible) and use it to set the material of your letters. It doesn't look very complicated, the *Specular* value seems pretty low, use a Noise Texture to give it some details, use an image as reference to make it as close as possible to the original. If you want it to look like metal, then push the *Metallic* value up to 1 and tweak the *Roughness* value:

[image]

- Disable the sun and bring 2 or 3 spots, set the value, here 60,000 W, and color it a bit so that it matches your reference:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much moonboots for your appreciated help! It is looking much more better and much more matching to the reference than when I first set it by myself! Thanks for downloading the file and for helping me with the correct settings!

Comment: you're welcome  ;)